# Why were pgp signatures directly appended to the header rather than storing them in a blob and referencing them?

Tags: git

If one looks at how a pgp signature is added to a git commit object, we see that it’s added by inserting the PEM encoded signature right on the next line after the header:

```
$ git cat-file -p 1b51f44d6b1e6c6eff3302a4af5a2b983a5d2161
tree fc069c67c550c449ff001fec804ad98c04c128da
parent bf17d1df5061aa67e4647fa3f7f3abd2cbe045ee
author Tim Lucas <t@toolmantim.com> 1473126017 +1000
committer Tim Lucas <t@toolmantim.com> 1473126017 +1000
gpgsig -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
 Version: GnuPG v1
 
 iQIcBAABAgAGBQJXzh6fAAoJEEWaob2jtb+GzVEQAIDh2MFyF90ui00/hssG2ehW
 cKImqo5VvDmv+j9oo+QL5MiH4Xv/pJ0VgcdTksmWnXx5+YyT1GsnnGkHg84Z/r/C
 PFHiWQKdPSOPg1DWtNrjsLgiIqPrInzBdXTcvdINCFvi8z7b6BHg2y444gJRg302
 e0vmMdo/eB0XC94rPujdguv2Lt9uZRjIC8tAc0JtNDA83nxbCAd8aMR8CzIZF9h6
 LE582fVA78sA+6dvCeMwzGWlnb3MEZToopLQgUBISAwvG/MdRSjMhArRrgNXHLfU
 3aRcwmoq/iVQSsQyCz8IMYifarY3gpJET3qsENvF8qqy9Z44JaBAo8Y+G1OmcaTw
 0eJgJFy3AyvQv75gcIfdHMh80MJFEEz9KfpH9jd8ZwE7ZkscIgoVEbM1FoGiAcEZ
 EpahmI1CWDcU3LkOK/fo+dFSgPBCNn5jndurj4oTWDhX91dg9vE/SpKSUk3jGXpO
 7FAZTgTlFXEkczhfxUMYRJ0j2s7rSzfA7OzvECkA+6OiOuxGFtvU+i+TT9YgI/dE
 QgQDh3LvNrnf1MrAg8dOek1AruQo1bkJZtjU5Km1N1YsU+SJr8Z4uR/sQQdrYC4u
 1Df5xhgI1GkfUFe0Pxwrs/WK/g4Nl3ltgnewgUwCRCwoXACWxpVikvyvM3Y4q42Y
 6Zc7kK3pPACaH8lwgr4g
 =4YLH
 -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

Fix account billing links
```

To me this doesn’t look very clean for two reasons:

1. While so far header fields were all single line, now a multiline content is added
2. Worse, it adds an empty line into the header, whereas it seems even the git code itself identifies the end of the header by searching for the first \n\n https://github.com/git/git/blob/4151fdb1c76c1a190ac9241b67223efd19f3e478/commit.c#L1006

To me it would have seemed cleaner  to `git hash-object -w <signature>` and then add a single line to the header `gpgsig <signature object-hash>`

My question is why it was instead directly postfixed to the existing header? The only thing that comes mind is backwards compatibility with older git clients, but those couldn’t verify the signatures anyway...

Does anyone know what lead to the decision to design the commit signatures this way?

Answer (score 0):

Git commits already use an empty line to distinguish headers from the commit message, so adding a signature here doesn't change that.  But this design has a couple of neat features:

- The signature is part of the hash of the object and is therefore immutable.  Nobody can add or remove a signature after the fact, which helps prevent tampering or forging signatures.  It's not possible to "lose" the signature by losing the blob.
- Referring to a blob in this way would be different from all of the other reachability checks that are done in Git, so using a commit like this and running `git gc` with an older Git would result in the signature blobs being deleted as unreferenced, since it wouldn't know about the new reference field.
- Such a signature wouldn't make a lot of logical sense as a blob and would be more appropriately a new object type, and that would have caused even more problems with backwards compatibility.

Comment: “ Git commits already use an empty line to distinguish headers from the commit message” that’s exactly what i mean - because now the header contains an empty line because the signature content contains an empty line

Comment: “ The signature is part of the hash of the object and is therefore immutable. Nobody can add or remove a signature after the fact, which helps prevent tampering or forging signatures. It's not possible to "lose" the signature by losing the blob.” that would also be the case if it was stored in a blob and referenced in the header by its object hash

Comment: “ Referring to a blob in this way would be different from all of the other reachability checks that are done in Git, so using a commit like this and running git gc with an older Git would result in the signature blobs being deleted as unreferenced, since it wouldn't know about the new reference field.” So this is the backwards compatibility that i mentioned, but since older clients can’t verify the signature anyway, i don’t see how that would be a problem

Comment: The "empty line" in the signature is actually a line containing a single space.  And it's a goal of Git not to lose your data unless you specifically ask it to, so losing signatures due to an older version of Git would be bad.